# How to compute the coefficient of a generating function?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I would like to find a closed formula for the coefficients of the generating function
$$f(x)=-{\frac {{x}^{4}+6\,{x}^{3}-2\,{x}^{2}+6\,x+1}{ \left( x+1 \right) 
 \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( x-1 \right) ^{3}}} .$$

I am trying to do the following.
\begin{align}
f(x)=\sum_{i,j,k_1,k_2,k_3=0}^{\infty} (-x)^i (-x^2)^j x^{k_1+k_2+k_3}(1+6x-2x^2+6x^3+x^4).
\end{align}

The expression is very complicated. Are there some simpler method (or some software) to find a closed formula for the coefficients? Thank you very much.

Comment: Tried partial fractions? $$-{x^4+6x^3-2x^2+6x+1\over(x+1)(x^2+1)(x-1)^3}={A\over x+1}+{Bx+C\over x^2+1}+{D\over x-1}+{E\over(x-1)^2}+{F\over(x-1)^3}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$-{\frac {{x}^{4}+6\,{x}^{3}-2\,{x}^{2}+6\,x+1}{ \left( x+1 \right) 
 \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( x-1 \right) ^{3}}} =\frac{0.25}{1-x}-\frac{0.75}{1+x}+\frac{x}{1+x^2}-\frac{1.5}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{3}{(1-x)^3}$$
then use the following series and differentiate it two times to replace all terms to series
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$$

Answer (score 1):

Split into partial fractions, use the generalized binomial theorem:

$\begin{align*}
   (1 - u)^{-m}
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} (-1)^n \binom{-m}{n} u^n \\\\
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n + m - 1}{m - 1} u^n
\end{align*}$

and you are all set:

$\begin{align*}
  [x^n] f(x)
     &= [x^n] \left(
                \frac{x}{1 + x^2}
                  - \frac{3}{4} \frac{1}{1 + x}
                  + \frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{1 - x}
                  - \frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2}
                  + 3 \frac{1}{(1 - x)^3}
              \right) \\\\
     &= [x^{n - 1}] \frac{1}{1 + x^2}
          - \frac{3}{4} \cdot (-1)^n
          + \frac{1}{4}
          - \frac{3}{2} \binom{n + 2 - 1}{2 - 1}
          + 3 \binom{n + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} \\\\
     &= [n \text{ odd}]
          - \frac{3}{4} \cdot (-1)^n
          + \frac{6 n^2 + 12 n + 7}{4}
\end{align*}$

Here $[n \text{ odd}]$ is Iverson's convention: 1 if the condition is true, 0 otherwise.